# Configure NoOpPasswordEncoder in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this configuration in Spring for passwords.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

But looks like it's deprecated, I don't need to encrypt rest keys. I need to store them in plain text. How I can configure this?

Answer (score 2):

just copy the code to MyNoOpPasswordEncoder, done! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This `PasswordEncoder` has been deprecated, because of this issue - [SEC-2564: Deprecate all salted digest password encoding #2776](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2776) (Spring Security at GitHub). It's not like it was secure or more reliable before deprecation (since it does nothing anyway), it was just deprecated as a part of something bigger.

If you want to use that `PasswordEncoder`, you can do that and ignore the deprecation, just know that it does completely nothing (maybe besides giving someone not familiar with the codebase a false sense of security) and as the docs says - should be used only for testing.

If you really want to avoid using this class, and you want to keep stuff in plaintext, and still for some reason declare `PasswordEncoder` as a bean (I don't really understand why would someone want combination of those 3 things) then you can implement your own `PasswordEncoder`, it's a simple interface.

Comment: I removed it and I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"`

Comment: ```ìd``` means identifier for look up which ```PasswordEncoder```. In normally, format of encoded password is ```{format}password```. So, you should to make your password like ```{noop}password```

Comment: What Spring method should I use to insert the password in order to have {noop}password?

Answer (score 1):

Though a little late, here is what I found:

If you want to store the password as plaintext you will have to prefix it with `{noop}`. Default `PasswordEncoder` i.e `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` should take care of matching it.
For e.g. if your plaintext password is `abc123ABC` you will have to store it in database as `{noop}abc123ABC`

(Valid for `Spring Security 5.x` onwards)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `"{noop}yourpasswordhere"`

Example

```java
var user = User.withUsername("john")
               .password("{noop}1234")
               .build();
```